# I have this Error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:

Tags: laravel

Controller two functions

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function  login(Request $request){
        if($request->is Method('post')){
            $data =$request->input();
            if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data,['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1'])){
                //echo "Success"; exit;
                  return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                echo "Failed"; exit;
            }
        }

        return view ('admin.admin_login');
    }
```

and This is the error I get SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` in (z6vCfv4iWVDd1mwdGv1gFc0DvP6E0d0ur1KtO1Em, johndoe@gmail.com, admin@1234) and `0` in (email) and `admin` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: you seem to have a stray comma in `$data,['email']`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put the whole `$data` array in the `attempt`.
Replace `if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data,'email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1']))` by
`if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1']))`